# On the new Activity,

Tags: java, if-statement, android-activity, structure

I want to ask that how can I use "if" structure in the new activity which is related to a string on the main activity.

here is my new activity ;

```
public class yeniaktivite extends Activity {
    public ImageView Abir;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yeniaktivite);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String id = intent.getStringExtra("key");

        if (id == "A2") {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Abir = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Abir.setImageResource(R.drawable.abir);
    }

}
```

this code ignores the if structure on running

Comment: The actual question is not really a question. Please improve the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you did it is completely correct (structure-wise). The issue is the way you are comparing strings.

You can't use `==` to compare two strings - it has to be `.equals()`. Change your if statement to

```
if(id.equals("A2") {
    //do whatever here
}
```